# Is there a methodology to assign integer values to factors in R

Tags: r, analysis

I am quite new to R, but was wondering if there is a specific way to group/analyze integer values from my data frame i.e.,

Sample X   : int 1 2 3 4 5

Sample Y   : int 6 7 8 9 10

Sample Z   : int 11 12 13 14 15

and assign these to my factor variable which has the corresponding number of levels (5 in this example) which are called in this example lvl 1, lvl 2, lvl 3, lvl 4, lvl 5. The goal is to be able to graph the observations at each level, for example lvl 1 had the observations 1, 6, and 11/ lvl 2 had 2, 7, and 12, etc.

I've found no clean way to do this. Other attempts have including individually typing out the name of each sample and manually linking this to the factor levels, but that has not gone well.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you add a sketch to your question and show what that plot should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to have each `x`, `y` and `z` observations associated with a level and plot by level.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df = data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 6:10, z = 11:15)

df$level = factor(paste0("lvl",1:5))

df
df
#  x  y  z level
# 1 1  6 11  lvl1
# 2 2  7 12  lvl2
# 3 3  8 13  lvl3
# 4 4  9 14  lvl4
# 5 5 10 15  lvl5
```

It's easier to use long formatted data for plot (with `ggplot2` package). I use `reshape2::melt` here but you could find equivalent solution with `tidyr::pivot_long`

```r
df <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "level")
df
   level variable value
1   lvl1        x     1
2   lvl2        x     2
3   lvl3        x     3
4   lvl4        x     4
5   lvl5        x     5
6   lvl1        y     6
7   lvl2        y     7
8   lvl3        y     8
9   lvl4        y     9
10  lvl5        y    10
11  lvl1        z    11
12  lvl2        z    12
13  lvl3        z    13
14  lvl4        z    14
15  lvl5        z    15
```

Finally, you can plot. Let's say you want points for each level:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = level, y = value)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks so much! Say for example you wanted to then try to plot by sample and show the density at each level, would this be possible by using a method similar to above?

Comment: Yes, it works. You could use `geom_density` for instance [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density.html).

Comment: Awesome, thank you, I truly appreciate all of the help. And apologies this has essentially turned into a lesson rather than simply asking for R help. I suppose my last question would be: I am now attempting to put my data in a violin plot format, but am getting warnings that say: 1: In max(data$density): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf 2:Computation failed in ' stat_ydensity()': replacement has 1 row, data has 0 Would these make sense in the context of these data?

Comment: Apologies for the spam! I thought I would update, I changed the y axis to a numeric which has worked- although it has obviously changed my variable names to numbers (not great but I'll deal with that), but at least the data are plotted in the violin formate, albeit I have a ways to go!